# 'right' property not working properly

Tags: css

Consider this:

```
.foo {
           position:absolute;
           left:25px;
           top:10px;
           width:130px;
           height:55px;
        }
```

And then this:

```
.change2 .foo {
           left:45px;
           top:90px;  
        }
```

The change works like a charm. When changed to this however (basically switched left to right):

```
.change1 .foo {
           right:15px;
           top:90px;
        }
```

It doesn't work. Question is why.
Entire source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>

    <title>error example</title>
    <style>
        .Body { 
            position:relative;
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
            height:400px;
            width:400px;
            border:1px dashed black;
            font-size:14px;
        }

        .foo {
           position:absolute;
           left:25px;
           top:10px;
           width:130px;
           height:55px;
        }

        .change1 .foo {
           right:15px;
           top:90px;
        }

        .change2 .foo {
           left:45px;
           top:90px;  
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="Body change1">
    <div class="foo">asdsdada</div> 

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to set the left property. By setting right, you aren't overriding the left, unless you explicitly set the left, for example to `auto` or `inherit`. If an element has both a left and right then the left will be used unless you set the left to `auto` or `inherit`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ht9uJ/)

```
.change1 .foo {
   right:15px;
   left:auto;
   top:90px;
}
```

Comment: I see. I had not considered that I have to set the left property as well. (Although it is quite logical now that I think about it.)

Comment: Yes it's because of the way the browser takes the left by default if both are set to a unit value :)

Comment: `left` and `right` can of course work together – the problem here is that a `width` is defined as well. If you want to use both left and right, then width has to be `auto`.

Answer (score 2):

```
.foo {
    position:absolute;
    left:25px;  // already specified 
    top:10px;
    width:130px;
    height:55px;
}
```

**CONFLICT**.

```
.change1 .foo {
    right:15px;
    top:90px;
    left: auto;  // reset it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.change1 .foo {
left: auto;
right:15px;
top:90px;
}
```